# Stack Overflow add resume in Job Preferences from iPhone 6S

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs, user-interface

[image]I'm using my iPhone 6S to add my resume to my Stack Overflow job preferences using the Dropbox option.

After selecting the resume file and clicking *Choose*, nothing seems to happen. How does it get uploaded to the site?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the Dropbox button? I just tried to replicate the issue and I'm only getting a Google Drive option.

Comment: I just tried this again and the Dropbox seems to be working so I'm marking this as non-repro. Please let me know if you're still having and issue with the Dropbox upload.